# Mocking generated API service

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ng-mocks

In our Angular application, we are using services generated from API and we're facing issues with the unit tests for components or custom services that utilize them.

```
// Generated code
getCurrentConnection(observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {
    httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*';
}): Observable<ConnectionResultDto>;
getCurrentConnection(observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {
    httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*';
}): Observable<HttpResponse<ConnectionResultDto>>;
getCurrentConnection(observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {
    httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*';
}): Observable<HttpEvent<ConnectionResultDto>>;
```

Usage in the custom made service

```
public getConnection(): Observable<ConnectionResultDto> {
  return this.connectionServiceAPI.getCurrentConnection('body').pipe(tap(res => this.updateConnectionStatus(res)));
}
```

And an attempt to mock it in unit test (we are using Jest + Spectator + Ng-Mocks)

```
describe('ConnectionService', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorHttp<ConnectionService>;
  const createHttp = createHttpFactory({
    service: ConnectionService,
    providers: [
      MockProvider(ConnectionControllerService, {
        getCurrentConnection: ('body') => of(CONNECTION_MOCK) // this throws error displayed below
      }),
    ],
  });
```

And this is the error we get (VS Code underlined)

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(instance: AnyType<ConnectionControllerService>, overrides?: Partial<ConnectionControllerService>): FactoryProvider', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ (observe?: "body", reportProgress?: boolean, options?: { httpHeaderAccept?: "*/*"; }): Observable<ConnectionResultDto>; (observe?: "response", reportProgress?: boolean, options?: { ...; }): Observable<...>; (observe?: "events", reportProgress?: boolean, options?: { ...; }): Observable<...>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(provider: string | InjectionToken<{ getCurrentConnection: string; }>, useValue?: Partial<{ getCurrentConnection: string; }>): FactoryProvider', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof ConnectionControllerService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | InjectionToken<{ getCurrentConnection: string; }>'.
      Type 'typeof ConnectionControllerService' is missing the following properties from type 'InjectionToken<{ getCurrentConnection: string; }>': _desc, ɵprov
  Overload 3 of 3, '(provider: string, useValue?: Partial<{ getCurrentConnection: string; }>): FactoryProvider', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof ConnectionControllerService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2769)
connectionController.service.d.ts(45, 5): The expected type comes from property 'getCurrentConnection' which is declared here on type 'Partial<ConnectionControllerService>'
(method) getCurrentConnection?(observe?: "body", reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {
    httpHeaderAccept?: "*/*";
}): Observable<ConnectionResultDto> (+2 overloads)
```

Any idea how can we mock it correctly? I tried specifying every optional parameter of the `getCurrentConnection` method but with no effect. Mocking without overriding methods will fail the unit tests because of the `pipe` operator on the undefined results.

Comment: `('body') => of(CONNECTION_MOCK)` isn't valid syntax for an arrow function, a parameter needs a _name_.

Comment: I fail to come up with working version of arrow function. How should it be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that typescript aggregates all parameters and all return types. Therefore, its mock should also follow the aggregated type.

In this case, `(_: 'body') => of(CONNECTION_MOCK)` is just 1 of 3.
Typescript expects `_` to be `'body' | 'response' | 'events'`, and the same happens with the return type: all 3 should be respected.

All that leads to the point that it's simpler to use `as never`, because it's hard to implement the desired callback.

```js
MockProvider(ConnectionControllerService, {
  getCurrentConnection: (_: 'body') => of(CONNECTION_MOCK),
} as never); // as never
```

or weaker options

```js
// jasmine
MockProvider(ConnectionControllerService, {
  getCurrentConnection: jasmine
    .createSpy()
    .and.returnValue(of(CONNECTION_MOCK)),
});

// jest
MockProvider(ConnectionControllerService, {
  getCurrentConnection: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue(of(CONNECTION_MOCK)),
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both options are working